# How do I run a long-running stored procedure on SQL Server, even if I get disconnected?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a stored procedure in an Azure SQL Database that does not return a result and can take several hours to run. It takes one parameter, and I am running it through the query editor window in Management Studio on my local machine:

```
EXEC @return_value = dbo.ComputeBatchData @BatchId = 2
```

My problem: If I get disconnected, the procedure is cancelled.

The procedure does not need to run on a schedule or anything. I just want to run the procedure and not have to worry about disconnects.

Comment: "On an Azure server" - could you please be a bit more specific here? Answers may differ depending on whether you mean SQL Server on a Windows Azure VM (where you can use a job or service broker) or Azure SQL Database (where you can't).

Comment: I mean an Azure Database where I can't use Service Broker functions. I found out that I couldn't use SB when I tried to implement this http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Answer (score 0):

Azure Automation: [Schedule the Execution of SQL Jobs in Azure with Automation Service](https://www.netwoven.com/2017/12/12/schedule-execution-sql-jobs-azure-automation-service/)

and make a small powershell script and schedule it in the azure dashboard.

Comment: I've been informed that Azure Scheduler will be removed after September 2019. They suggested using Logic Apps instead.